# What does i_tmp2 stand for when used as a variable?

Tags: php

Sorry for a noobish question but I've stumbled upon some other person's code and he is using `i_tmp2` inside of a `for` loop. When is the `i_tmp2` notation used?

Comment: I don't think this deserves to be downvoted as it's only a rookie mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i in i_tmp2 probably stands for "integer", i.e. telling you it's a variable used for storing whole numbers.

tmp2 in i_tmp2 probably just means it's the second temporary variable created.

Comment: I thank everyone who took the time to answer. I think this explanation comes closest to deciphering the meaning behind this variable naming.

Answer (score 2):

Ask the person who actually wrote the code.  Every individual programmer has their own reasons for choosing their notation styles for particular types of code.

Answer (score 0):

It is used when the programmer isn't very good.

Oh come on, it's a joke.

Comment: And you can tell this from one variable name?

Comment: Yes you absolutely can tell this from one variable name.  All good programming methods include strict rules on variable naming particularly the use of meaningful variable names. I always prefix variables with their type so at least it looks like he is doing that part right.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slightly outdated variabla naming convention called *Hungarian notation*, credited mostly to Charles Simonyi, a Hungarian programmer worked for Microsoft.
With HN, the first character of the variable name is i for integer, l for long, w for word, etc. It is (was) useful with strongly typed languages to keep all the programmers remembering the type of the variables used/expected by functions.

Nowdays it is mostly out of fashion :)